# Как проверить значение и сделать редирект в JS?

Tags: javascript, qr

Имеется следующий код

```
<b>Detected QR code: </b>
<span id="cam-qr-result">None</span>

<script type="module">
import QrScanner from "qr-scanner.min.js";
QrScanner.WORKER_PATH = 'qr-scanner-worker.min.js';

const video = document.getElementById('qr-video');
const camHasCamera = document.getElementById('cam-has-camera');
const camHasFlash = document.getElementById('cam-has-flash');
const flashToggle = document.getElementById('flash-toggle');
const flashState = document.getElementById('flash-state');
const camQrResult = document.getElementById('cam-qr-result');
const camQrResultTimestamp = document.getElementById('cam-qr-result-timestamp');
const fileSelector = document.getElementById('file-selector');
const fileQrResult = document.getElementById('file-qr-result');

function setResult(label, result) {
    label.textContent = result;
    camQrResultTimestamp.textContent = new Date().toString();
    label.style.color = 'teal';
    clearTimeout(label.highlightTimeout);
    label.highlightTimeout = setTimeout(() => label.style.color = 'inherit', 100);
}

// ####### Web Cam Scanning #######

QrScanner.hasCamera().then(hasCamera => camHasCamera.textContent = hasCamera);

const scanner = new QrScanner(video, result => setResult(camQrResult, result), error => {
    camQrResult.textContent = error;
    camQrResult.style.color = 'inherit';
});
scanner.start().then(() => {
    scanner.hasFlash().then(hasFlash => {
        camHasFlash.textContent = hasFlash;
        if (hasFlash) {
            flashToggle.style.display = 'inline-block';
            flashToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
                scanner.toggleFlash().then(() => flashState.textContent = scanner.isFlashOn() ? 'on' : 'off');
            });
        }
    });
});

// for debugging
window.scanner = scanner;

document.getElementById('show-scan-region').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    const input = e.target;
    const label = input.parentNode;
    label.parentNode.insertBefore(scanner.$canvas, label.nextSibling);
    scanner.$canvas.style.display = input.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
});

document.getElementById('inversion-mode-select').addEventListener('change', event => {
    scanner.setInversionMode(event.target.value);
});

document.getElementById('start-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    scanner.start();
});

document.getElementById('stop-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    scanner.stop();
});

// ####### File Scanning #######

fileSelector.addEventListener('change', event => {
    const file = fileSelector.files[0];
    if (!file) {
        return;
    }
    QrScanner.scanImage(file)
        .then(result => setResult(fileQrResult, result))
        .catch(e => setResult(fileQrResult, e || 'No QR code found.'));
});
```

если просканировать QR-код то в ID-элемента "cam-qr-result" появляется результат, и хотелось бы посредством JS проверить если данное появилось то сделать редирект на url "sitedomain.ru"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const scanner = new QrScanner(video, 
  result => {
    setResult(camQrResult, result);
    window.location = "sitedomain.ru";
  }, 
  error => {
    camQrResult.textContent = error;
    camQrResult.style.color = 'inherit';
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Igor, спасибо за помощь, но похоже у меня появилась другая проблема, когда результат появляется происходит редирект, но результат является динамическим, те если дестабилизация камеры происходит то QR сканнер каждый раз пишет No  Qr Found или Выдает результат, тем временем происходит задержка в переходе (бесконечный цикл состояния перехода), как то можно первый результат поставить в куки и там уже его взять?

Comment: @DowJhonn Можно. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage